# How to add active with PHP include OR

Tags: php

```
<?php if($current_page=='page1' || 'sub1' or 'sub2' or 'sub3' or 'sub5'){echo 'active';} ?>
```

Hello friends,
If i write this code like this to the caption's class of sub-menu, all the captions who has sub menu going to active.
My pages decomposed like header.php, footer.php.
In every inner page, on the top of the page i write this code

```
<?php ob_start(); session_start(); $current_page='page1'; include 'header.php';?>
```

Oranges are active :
[image: oranges are active]

Comment: Can you describe what your problem is? What is the expected behaviour and what is wrong currently?

Comment: `if ($current_page == "page1" || $current_page == "sub1" || ...)`

Comment: For example:
Page1 (Caption)
   SubButton1
   SubButton2
   SubButton3

Page2 (Caption)
   SubButton1
   SubButton2
   SubButton3

If i click page2->subbutton3 i only want Page2 and SubButton3 being active. But in my code all the captions where i added going active.

Comment: on the picture i added u can see the buttons gone active (orange).

Comment: Could you share the html for the menu please?

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/0ea4228d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem is with your if statement. PHP treats a non empty string as true so each of the "or" conditions return true. You would need to specify "$current_page ==" in each "or" condition

i.e

```
<?php if($current_page=='page1' || $current_page=='sub1' || $current_page=='sub2' || $current_page=='sub3' || $current_page=='sub5'){echo 'active';} ?>
```

But that is very long. A much more concise approach would be to use "in_array": https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

i.e.

```
<?php if(in_array($current_page, array('page1','sub1','sub2','sub3','sub5'))){echo 'active';} ?>
```

Comment: Mark thanks a lot my friend. The array sollution did work. Thanks bro :)) Have a nice day